# after removing radio button selected value from js in aspx.cs selected value presists

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a asp radio button list control as below:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radio2" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <asp:ListItem  Text="YES" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem  Text="NO" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="submit" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" />
```

when page loads on browser I select yes option radio.
Then from console i remove checked property of it as this:

```
$("#radio2 input[type='radio']").prop("checked",false);
```

Now if i try to access radio button list on click of button submit as below

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListItem itemRow in radio2.Items)
            {
                if (itemRow.Selected)
                { }
            }
        }
```

Here for yes itemrow I got selected value as true while it should be false.

Comment: in code itself you are setting Selected="True"..

Answer (score 0):

***What is the requirement ?*** please Explain properly.
itemrow you got selected value as true Because,only page load time clearing that checked property in script. but in design you written
"`<asp:ListItem  Text="NO" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>`" 
thats why it takes default value of RadioButton list.
Remove tht ***Selected="True"***  so it will not take any default value.

Comment: Remove that selected=true from design and try it.

Comment: Sorry , I can not understand your requirement properly. please explain Briefly. @Suman Rajpura